# SQL Database Foreign Key issue(The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Orders__Employee__0F624AF8"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Any help would be much appreciated as this is my first sql project.I have created the tables in the right order but when I try to insert data into the `orders` table it throws an error. Please check last table when inserting into orders. Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
SupplierId int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
CompanyName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
ContactName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
City  nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Homepage ntext NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_Suppliers PRIMARY KEY (SupplierId)

 )  
  INSERT INTO Suppliers
(CompanyName,ContactName,City,Phone,Homepage)
VALUES
('GardenWorld','JimL','Dublin','085-1588902','Gardenworld.ie'),
('HomeFixLtd','AnneG','Cork','087-1584402','HomeFix.ie'),
('PleasureDome','PaulH','Dublin','086-3248902','PleasureDome.ie'),
('BuildBase','GarthN','Belfast','004485-1588902','BuildBase.co.uk'),
('RenewTools','HarryH','Galway','087-4567835','RenewTools.ie')

CREATE TABLE Products
(
  ProductID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  SupplierId int NOT NULL,
  Category   nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
 UnitPrice money NOT NULL,
 UnitsInStock smallint NOT NULL,
  UnitsOnOrder smallint NOT NULL,
  ReOrderLevel smallint NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (SupplierId) REFERENCES Suppliers (SupplierId)

)
 INSERT INTO dbo.Products
    (ProductName,SupplierId,Category,UnitPrice,UnitsInStock,UnitsOnOrder,ReOrderLeve   l)
VALUES

('Fork Handles','1','Garden','10.00','125','0','25'),
 ('Hammer','2','DIY','3.00','129','0','40'),
('Bucket','4', 'Garden','5.00','25','30','30'),
('Solar Battery','2','DIY','15.00','112','0','35'), 
('Lawnmower','1','Garden','150.00','24','8','25'),
('Kitchen Sink','4','DIY','80.00','115','0','30'),
('Cement Bag','4','DIY','10.00','130','0','25'),
('Compost Bag','1','Garden','5.00','135','0','20'),
('Chainsaw','1','Garden','100.00','11','15','15'),
('Sun Lounger','3','Leisure','30.00','4','30','10'),
('Light Bulb','4','DIY','5.00','17','50','35'),
('Paint Set','5','DIY','10.00','25','0','30'),
('Ladder','2','DIY','28.00','5','20','10'),
 ('Wheel Barrow','1','Garden','50.00','125','0','24'),
 ('Dinghy','3','Leisure','100.00','4','20','10')

    CREATE TABLE Customers(
CustomerId int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
FirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
LastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
CompanyName nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
City nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Country nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
Email nvarchar(25) NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId))

  INSERT INTO Customers

   (FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,City,Country,Phone,Email)

  VALUES

  ('Edgar','Codd','n/a','Galway','Eire','085-1233456','ec@yahoo.com'),
  ('John','Byrne','JB Landscapes','Limerick','Eire','086-2347656','jc@gmail.com'),
  ('Jane','Ryan','n/a','Dublin','Eire','087-1569846','jr@live.com'),
  ('Bill','Bates','n/a','Cork','Eire','085-1245356','bb@yahoo.com'),
  ('Ridley','Scott','RS Carpentry','Galway','Eire','085-8933456','rs@yahoo.com'),
 ('Anne','Smith','n/a','Dublin','Eire','087-7988456','as@yahoo.com'),
  ('Paul','Jones','PJ Plumbers','Belfast','UK','085-          6723456','PJ@yahoo.com'),
  ('James','Ryan','JR Bros','London','UK','085-6723456','jr@yahoo.com'),
 ('Jim','Reilly','n/a','Cork','Eire','085-6888456','jj@yahoo.com'),
 ('Emily','Rigby','n/a','London','UK','085-6778946','er@gmail.com')

  CREATE TABLE Employees(
EmployeeId int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
LastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
Department nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
City nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Age smallint NOT NULL,
Salary int NOT NULL,
Commission_Pct decimal(2,2) NOT NULL
  )

   INSERT INTO Employees
   (FirstName,LastName,Department,City,Age,Salary,Commission_Pct)
  VALUES
  ('John','Cusack','Garden','Dublin','44','30000','0.00'),
  ('Todd','Louiso','DIY','Dublin','32','25000','0.05'),
   ('Jack','Black','Garden','Galway','22','22000','0.20'),
   ('Joan','Barrett','DIY','Dublin', '34','30000','0.05'),
   ('Barry','Behan','DIY', 'Belfast','55','35000','0.00')


 CREATE TABLE Orders
 (
  OrderID int IDENTITY(1,1)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CustomerID int NOT NULL,
  ProductID int NOT NULL,
  UnitPrice money NOT NULL,
  Quantity smallint NOT NULL,   
  EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
  OrderDate date NOT NULL,
  DispatchDate date NOT NULL,  
  FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProductID),
  FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId),
  FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId)
 )
```

Here is the problem `INSERT` on the `Orders` table

```
  INSERT INTO Orders
(CustomerID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,EmployeeID,OrderDate,DispatchDate)
 VALUES
('2','1','3.00','5','3','2017-05-19','2017-05-23'),
('3','4','15.00','2','4','2017-05-10','2017-05-19'),
('7','3','5.00','10','4','2017-05-14','2017-05-17'),
 ('5','9','100.00','3','8','2017-05-05','2017-05-11'),
('6','10','30.00','4','9','2017-05-05','2017-05-09'),
('1','8','5.00','10','4','2017-05-05','2017-05-07'),
('3','11','5.00','15','5','2017-05-11','2017-05-17'),
('7','13','28.00','3','2','2017-05-15','2017-05-19'),
('4','6','80.00','10','5','2017-05-15','2017-05-19'),
('10','5','150.00','2','1','2017-05-15','2017-05-18')
```

This generates the following error.

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Orders__Employee__0F624AF8". The conflict occurred in database "Billy Joes Hardware/Assignment", table "dbo.Employees", column 'EmployeeId'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table Orders you are inserting EmployeeId, check the 5th value is 9:

```
('6','10','30.00','4','9','2017-05-05','2017-05-09'),
```

And you have inserted only 5 records on Employees table, i'm pretty sure that your max id is 5, you can't use Employeeid=9 for Orders table because doesn't exist on Employees; and you have this restriction for Orders table: `FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId)`.

**Solution**

Before insert in Orders, first check what EmployeesId you have available on Employees table. To check this use `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES`

(Not recommended) In case you want to insert any EmployeesId values without restriction, then you should remove this line: `FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId)`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry!..this alone was causing the error .was going to put 10 employees in at start.All the Best

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you actually have 2 rows that would violate the constraint.

```
('5','9','100.00','3','8','2017-05-05','2017-05-11'),
('6','10','30.00','4','9','2017-05-05','2017-05-09')
```

If you run  `SELECT EmployeeId FROM Employees`, you will get this.

```
EmployeeId
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
```

Or you could run `SELECT MAX(EmployeeId) FROM Employees` and get **`5`** as the result.

You are receiving the error because the `EmployeeId` is **`8`** for the 4th row of your insert and **`9`** for the 5th row of your insert. Since you only have 5 rows in the `Employees` table, `8` and `9` are invalid `EmployeeId`'s. You either need to change the `EmployeeId` in your insert or insert some more rows into your `Employees` table

I created this diagram of your tables. This displays your foreign key relationships. This should help you see what valid value from one table is required in the other.

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason! ..was going to put in 10 employees at beginning ..This alone is causing the error.  and thanks for diagram should have began with this.